# Date Range picker with boot strap off canvas month and year dropdown flickering on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, datepicker, daterangepicker

Daterange picker month and year dropdown continuous flickering on mozila firefox.

There is issue with daterange picker and bootstrap offcanvas.

here is code snippet for that.

If anybody facing same issue than please help me to figure out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" id="demo">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h1 class="offcanvas-title">Heading</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
    <p>Some text lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p>Some text lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p>Some text lorem ipsum.</p>
    <input type="text" id="config-demo" class="form-control">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">A Button</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
  <h3>Offcanvas Sidebar</h3>
  <p>Offcanvas is similar to modals, except that it is often used as a sidebar.</p>
  
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#demo">
    Open Offcanvas Sidebar
  </button>
</div>

</body>
</html>

<script>
$('#config-demo').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    autoUpdateInput: false,
    opens: 'left',
    maxDate: new Date(),
});
</script>
```